# p/invoke calling C dll from c#

Tags: c#, c, dll, pinvoke

this is my C code

```
extern "C"
{ 
     __declspec(dllexport) void DisplayHelloFromDLL(string a)
   {    
     printf ("%s\n",a)
   }
}
```

---

this is my C# code

```
class HelloWorld
{
    [DllImport("TestLib.dll")]
    public static extern void DisplayHelloFromDLL(string a);

    static void Main ()
    {
        string a = "Hello";
        DisplayHelloFromDLL(a);
    }
}
```

---

It built successfully but crash like this:

[image: Debug]

SO,how to use P/invoke to call my own C dll from C#?
Please help,thanx in advance.

Comment: What is the `string` type in the "C" code? A `std::string`?

Comment: C has a `string` data-type? Try `char*`.

Comment: I have include <string>,its std::string..anyway, It showed "HELLO" successfully.

Comment: @Zombia Then you don't have a C DLL, but a C++ DLL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your code is C++ rather than C.  Your function receives a parameter of type `std::string` and the use of `std::string` means that your code is actually C++.

Now this parameter type is the root of your problem. You cannot create a `std::string` in .net and instead will need to use a `char*` to pass the string data. The following code is what you need:

**C++**

```
__declspec(dllexport) void DisplayHelloFromDLL(char* a)
{    
    printf("%s\n", a);
}
```

**C#**

```
[DllImport("TestLib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void DisplayHelloFromDLL(string a);

static void Main ()
{
    string a = "Hello";
    DisplayHelloFromDLL(a);
}
```

The default p/invoke marshalling for a .net `string` is to pass a `char*` as an `[In]` parameter. There is no need for the complexity of `IntPtr`, `StringToHGlobalAnsi`, `FreeHGlobal` as suggested by one of the other answers. If you can let the p/invoke marshaller do the work then it is preferable to do so.

Note that you also need to make sure that your calling conventions match. Under the assumption that you have not used any special compiler options when building your C++ code, that code will default to used `cdecl` calling convention. You can make that match with the `CallingConvention` parameter to the `DllImport` attribute.

Comment: Thanx.your solution also works for me and it looks greater..I am a newie and dont know which solution is better. Is there some reference I can learn from and make depth knowledge?

Comment: There are various topics and articles on MSDN but I know of no comprehensive reference that concentrates on pinvoke. This is an area where you seem to have to rely on lore.

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at [marshalling string at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s97shtze%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

In a nut shell,  a C# string doesn't get marshalled as `std::string` but a `char*` by default

Answer (score 1):

For one thing the return type is not matching. In C it is `void` and in C# `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Change your C++ param type to char* and update your C# code as following

```
class HelloWorld
{
  [DllImport("TestLib.dll")]
  public static extern void DisplayHelloFromDLL(IntPtr a);

  static void Main ()
  {
    string a = "Hello";
    var ptr = System.Runtime.Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(a);
    DisplayHelloFromDLL(ptr);
    System.Runtime.Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to  free the memory allocated by [StringToHGlobalAnsi](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.stringtohglobalansi.aspx).

Comment: yep that's true, I missed that completely, I'm updating the post

Comment: You need to invoke  FreeHGlobal, not ZeroFreeGlobalAllocAnsi.

Comment: And you should free the memory in a `finally`, in case the code between StringToHGlobalAnsi and FreeHGlobal throws an exception.

Comment: thanx a lot..I also changed the string type in C dll to char* type.And it works !

Comment: @Zombia Please do not accept this answer. It is incorrect. The problem was that your C++ code received `std::string`. There's no way to create one of those from .net. So the answer is that you simply need to change the C++ function to receive `char*` instead of `std::string`. That's the only change you need. Oh, and your code is C++ rather than C.

Comment: @Waleed What does that mean. Do you disagree with what I wrote. I see there is a down-vote on my answer. I'd imagine that came from you. If so then perhaps you could explain what I got wrong. This site is about giving people accurate advice. Your answer does not do that. If you disagree with me, make your case.

Comment: It means nothing, just that the code is working and that makes it a correct answer dot

Comment: @Waleed It only works if the C++ code is changed to `char*` and the calling conventions are made to match. So no the answer is incorrect.

Comment: First, I know that he should change the type to char* then you don't need to tell me all of that, the guy is telling us that it's working, it's just about your arrogant comment style, you might use some more formal expressions, you were so rough, after all I'm a student and I'm still learning for this great website dot dot

Comment: @Waleed I was just stating facts as I see them. My criticism is at least as much with Zombia as it is with you. Anyway, if you do know that `char*` is required here then please edit your question to say so. When a future visitor arrives at this page, your answer will be misleading. And you also failed to mention calling convention which is presumably a mismatch too. Since your answer is the accepted one it really ought to be factually correct. If you edited it to be so then I could delete my answer (which I believe to be correct) and these comments, and my downvote.

Comment: @Waleed I have tested that the primal problem is to change the defined type in C++ to char*, not the marshal things.It is my fault in the first place.Anyway,thanx for your answer.