# Call a function of DLL (written in VC++) from C#

Tags: c#, visual-c++, dll, dllexport

I have a DLL written in VC++ and I need to make use of the functions (available in DLL) in my C# Forms application. Tried using the export features available but nothing worked for me. Also I tried other possible solutions that I managed to get by browsing like the wrappers, p Invoke etc. Will be thankful if someone suggest a good working solution.

Comment: Did you try P/Invoke?

Comment: possible duplicate of [p/invoke calling C dll from c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891528/p-invoke-calling-c-dll-from-c-sharp)

Comment: Yeah I tried p/invoke :( I had the entry point issue

Comment: Pinvoke can only support static C++ functions.  You cannot directly use a C++ class with a constructor, that requires a wrapper written in C++/CLI.  Use dumpbin.exe /exports or the .map file generated by the linker to see the decorated function names that you need to use for the DllImport's EntryPoint property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your C++ code is generated as native code you can use the DllImportAttribute.

```
[DllImport("yourdll.dll")]
public extern returnType FunctionName (int p1, string p2); // the parameters are the same as the C++ function
```

For more information see the following link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468(v=vs.71).aspx

Good luck